# Which astra or celestial weapon contains the power of Shiva's third eye?

Tags: shiva, weapon

Shiva has many astras that are considered to be very destructive such as the Raudrastra and Pashupatastra. My exact question is which astra or celestial weapon contains the power of Shiva's third eye?

Comment: um.... his eye?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In bakthi marg it is called asthra the knowledge path of it is Knoweldge aiming to reolve questions. So these are the question of knowledge . Knolwedge number is i am a an athma a bindi ( a star but not physical) residing in btween my forehead. Supreme soul or paramathma shiva siting in the forehead of shanker > in bakthi marg all religion says god is sarva vyapi But knowledge is god is ekavyapi . He spread from shanker through the drishti ( third eye)

Comment: This is not an answer to his question.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).